# VBA - Calling function from within userform causes strange errors

Tags: excel, vba

I am encountering a strange error in Excel when executing a subroutine from a button within a userform.

The purpose of the form is to insert a new product into a long list of products and their details. The subroutine being called selects a range within the product list and calls the insert method on the range.

Once this subroutine has executed Excel begins behaving very strangely. If I select a cell and enter come characters then press enter the cell doesn't update. No modifications can be made to the product list sheet, and I cannot even exit Excel by clocking the X in the top right of the window. Sometimes when this happens, rows in other sheets get shifted.

The only way for Excel to become responsive again is to navigate to another sheet and modify a cell, which seems to set everything straight.

When I run the same subroutine from a button on the sheet, or from the macros menu the problem doesn't occur.

Any suggestions as to what might be going on here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Selection.ShapeRange.Name` to get the name of the selected shape. You'll need to trap the `Error 5 'Invalid procedure call or argument` that will be thrown if the Selection.ShapeRange doesn't have a name property.

```
    Dim ShapeName As String

    On Error Resume Next
    ShapeName = Selection.ShapeRange.Name
    On Error GoTo 0
    If InStr(ShapeName, "Text Box") Then
        'Do Something
    End If
```